# unable to modify specific column in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to be having an issue when updating records on a specific table.

For reference here is an example of the query that throws an error:

```
UPDATE `dbname`.`tblname` SET `CustomerID` = '543' WHERE `tblname`.`Issue_ID` = 440
```

I am able to insert, delete and query rows, as well as update other columns however whenever trying to update the CustomerID field (int, non-null) it throws an error saying:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'Revision' in 'field list'

I have all rights to both the database and table however while trying to update the CustomerID column on any rows, ever when Revision isn't even in the query I get the same error.

I looked around a great deal into the issue using a regex in my php code to remove all non-printable characters however even when running the query from phpMyAdmin the same error is thrown.

If anyone has insight into this error it would be greatly appreciated.

Table description:

[image]

Comment: *Hm...* any foreign keys?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No foreign keys.

Comment: column 'Revision'? That is the literal error? You don't reference a column by that name in this statement. Weird!

Comment: Is Revision a column on that table?  Can you share a table description, showing us the columns?

Comment: are you 100% sure of those column names and the database/table chosen? could also be a lettercase issue. Plus, since you did tag as PHP, can you show us exactly how your code looks like, quotes and all, connection and other probable relevant information you have left out where it could be relevant. It could be a quotes/ticks issue. So far, that is what I've found a few probable reasons on Google.

Comment: It is a column on the table, I will attach an image of the table description. @Fred-ii- I am certain, you can see it in the image above.

Comment: and you did remove the quotes around `= '543'` and all values match for both criterias? with no whitespace

Comment: Can you perform a select which involves column "Revision"?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may possibly encounter this if you have an update trigger firing off which is referencing a column that does not exist.  May be the offending trigger is not even trying to read/write to this table!  As such, that column may not exist where it is trying to reference it. Further, you could kick off a cascade of such triggers, and have this buried more than one layer deep.

To show triggers:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-triggers.html

To modify them:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: We do have a trigger when a value is updated on this table. I will post it the portion dealing with CustomerID in the question for ease of reading.

Comment: That indeed was the issue, in the trigger for update it inserts the row into another table which contains a field RevisionNumber however the procedure used mistakingly used Revision instead. Thank you very much.

Comment: please don't ask for that ^ you did a great job (bravo) but many don't appreciate people asking (the OP) to upvote *"You're welcome! Upvote, please? – BuvinJ 1 min ago"* and may get flagged for it. @BuvinJ if people feel it's worthy of an upvote, they will.

Comment: Thanks for the warning Fred.